# How to find if there are repeating numbers in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database is SQL Server. I've a phone number field. I've to return the value INVALID if the phone number contains same digit repeating more than 7 times? For example (401) 2510897 --> Valid. (401) 4444444 ----> Invalid.

Comment: Not sure, but i think you would need `\1` regex here, and i think thats not supported on MSSQL :/

Answer (score 1):

LIKE seems to do the job...

```
SELECT
    Telephone,
    CASE
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%3%3%3%3%3%3%3%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%4%4%4%4%4%4%4%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%5%5%5%5%5%5%5%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%6%6%6%6%6%6%6%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%7%7%7%7%7%7%7%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%8%8%8%8%8%8%8%' THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%9%9%9%9%9%9%9%' THEN 'Invalid'
        ELSE 'Valid'
    END
FROM
    MyTable
```

or using REPLICATE to make it clearer there must be less than 7 matches...

```
SELECT
    Telephone,
    CASE
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('0%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('1%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('2%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('3%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('4%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('5%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('6%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('7%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('8%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        WHEN Telephone LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('9%', 7) THEN 'Invalid'
        ELSE 'Valid'
    END
FROM
    MyTable
```

Comment: The only issue is that "more than 7" really means `8`.  I should also note that this is easily adapted if the "more than 7" really means more than 7 times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to take this requirement into the program to deal with, or use clr. If you must use t-sql, you can do it like this:

```
-- Auxiliary function, this function is very commonly used and can be left in the database
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitByTrunk](@str varchar(max), @len int = 1)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    with c0 as(
    select @str as s
    ), c1 as(
    select number+1 as n from master.dbo.spt_values where type = 'P' and number >= 0 and number%@len = 0
    )
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c1.n) as pos
           , SUBSTRING(c0.s, c1.n, @len) as item
    from c0
    inner join c1 on c1.n <= LEN(c0.s)
)

-- Then
create table #temp(num varchar(32))
insert into #temp(num) values('(401) 2510897'), ('(401) 4444444')

select num
       , (case when (select MAX(cnt)
                     from(select COUNT(*) as cnt from [dbo].[SplitByTrunk](num, 1) group by item) as d) < 7
               then 'Valid.'
          else 'Invalid.'
          end) as isvalid
from #temp
```

The master.dbo.spt_values in the function SplitByTrunk, if the number sequence is not long enough, you can use the following function instead (this function is also very commonly used and can be retained in the database)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNums](@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH
        L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (VALUES(1),(1)) AS D(c)),
        L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
        L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
        L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
        L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
        L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
        Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
                 FROM L5)
SELECT @low + rownum - 1 AS n
FROM Nums
ORDER BY rownum
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST @high - @low + 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using some window functions and a recursive cte, but - depending on the number of records - the perofrmance won't be that good I guess:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  TelID int,
  TelNo VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
  (1, '(401) 4444444')
 ,(2, '(401) 4444344')

;WITH cteTelPos AS(
SELECT TelID, TelNo, 1 id, LEFT(TelNo, 1) AS TelPos, RIGHT(TelNo, LEN(TelNo)-1) AS tel
  FROM @t
UNION ALL
SELECT TelID, TelNo, id+1, LEFT(tel, 1), RIGHT(tel, LEN(tel)-1)
  FROM cteTelPos
  WHERE LEN(tel) >= 1
),
cteFilterGrp AS(
SELECT TelID, TelNo, id, TelPos
      ,(id - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TelPos ORDER BY id)) * RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TelPos) AS grp
  FROM cteTelPos
),
cteInval AS(
SELECT TelID, TelNo, TelPos, Grp, COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM cteFilterGrp
  GROUP BY TelID, TelNo, TelPos, Grp
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 7
),
cteInvalSrt AS(
SELECT TelID, TelNo, TelPos, Grp, cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn
  FROM cteInval
)
SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN s.cnt IS NULL THEN N'Valid' ELSE N'Invalid' END AS TelStatus
  FROM @t AS t
  LEFT JOIN cteInvalSrt s ON s.TelID = t.TelID AND s.rn = 1
```